# Cordova 3.5.0 FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR (Code:1) Error uploading files > 256MB

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

```
Cordova 3.5.0
FileTransfer 0.4.4
iPad 2 version 7.1.2
error: FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR (Code:1)
Error uploading files iOS > 256MB
```

Log device:

```
Jul 15 17:12:34 iPad-Sergej CueVu[119] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['Camera'] took '18.839844' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Jul 15 17:13:24 iPad-Sergej CueVu[119] <Warning>: Error opening file file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/D51C7F13-09AE-42D3-A613-83D5005C55F2/tmp/trim.ED614CFF-CBE0-4A8C-82D2-E507F3DA9B0D.MOV: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldnt be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x1a978b60 {NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Applications/D51C7F13-09AE-42D3-A613-83D5005C55F2/tmp/trim.ED614CFF-CBE0-4A8C-82D2-E507F3DA9B0D.MOV, NSUnderlyingError=0x14dfa590 "The operation couldnt be completed. Cannot allocate memory"}
Jul 15 17:13:24 iPad-Sergej CueVu[119] <Warning>: FileTransferError {
code = 1;
source = "file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/D51C7F13-09AE-42D3-A613-83D5005C55F2/tmp/trim.ED614CFF-CBE0-4A8C-82D2-E507F3DA9B0D.MOV";
target = "https://myserver.com/my/mobile/uploadFile/t:153c52738326e2153c5273832ac7153c5273832eb0153c5273833298";
}
Jul 15 17:13:24 iPad-Sergej CueVu[119] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['FileTransfer'] took '39.189209' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Jul 15 17:13:24 iPad-Sergej CueVu[119] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '67.596924' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

Code:

```
function uploadVideo(meeting_id) {
var chargeBar = '';

 navigator.camera.getPicture(        
     successGetFileFromCamera,
     failGetFileFromCamera,
     { 
         quality: 50,
         destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
         sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
         mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.VIDEO
     }
 );

function successGetFileFromCamera(fileURI) {
    uploadFileToServ(fileURI);
} 

function failGetFileFromCamera(message) {
    showError(message);         
}

function uploadFileToServ(fileURI) {
    alert(fileURI);
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "my_video";
    options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="video/mp4";
    var params = {};
    params.meeting_id = meeting_id;
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = true;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();        
    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if(progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
          updateProgress(Number(((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100).toFixed(1)));                        
        }
    };

    showProgress();

    ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI(window.cuevuHost + "/cuevu/mobile/uploadFile/t:" + window.cuevuToken), successUploadFileToServ, failUploadFileToServ, options);
}

function showProgress() {       
    $("#progress_window").popup('open');
    $("#progress_window_content").html("<div id='chargeBar'></div>");
    chargeBar = new Progress.bar({ id: "progress1", autoRemove: false, backgroundSpeed: 5, type: "charge", showPercentage: true});
    chargeBar.renderTo(document.getElementById('chargeBar'));
    $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
}   

function updateProgress(value) {
    chargeBar.update(value);
} 

function closeProgress() {
    $("#progress_window").popup('close');
}

function successUploadFileToServ(r) {       
    closeProgress();        
    data = $.parseJSON(r.response);
    if(data.result == true) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Video file has been successfully loaded', null, 'Upload file', null);
    } else {
        dataHaveError(data);
    }
}

function failUploadFileToServ(error) {
    closeProgress();
    showError("File Transfer: Code = " + error.code);       
}

}
```

Please help, what is the cause of the error can not understand...

Answer (score 0):

Please change your implementation of uploadFileToServ function to below

```
function uploadFileToServ(fileURI) {
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURI, function (fileEntry) {
fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
var fileName = fileObj.fullPath;

alert(fileName);
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "my_video";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="video/mp4";
var params = {};
params.meeting_id = meeting_id;
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = true;

var ft = new FileTransfer();        
ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if(progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
      updateProgress(Number(((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100).toFixed(1)));                        
    }
};

showProgress();

ft.upload(fileName encodeURI(window.cuevuHost + "/cuevu/mobile/uploadFile/t:" +    window.cuevuToken),    successUploadFileToServ, failUploadFileToServ, options);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Only instead of the `fullPath` used `localURL`.
Only now another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867759/app-crash-when-loading-a-file-256mb-on-the-ipad